# UIControlEventTouchDragInside Issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

in Viewdidload where CandidateView is custom viewcontroller

```
for (int i = 0; i < 9 ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        CandidateView *candView = [[CandidateView alloc]init];
        candView.view.frame = CGRectMake(15 + i*186 ,17 + j*145, 158,130);
        [candView.btnCandidate addTarget:self action:@selector(wasDragged:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
        [mainScroll addSubview:candView.view];
    }
}
```

This is the method

```
-(void)wasDragged:(UIButton *)button withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:button] anyObject];
    // get delta
    CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:button];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:button];
    CGFloat delta_x = location.x - previousLocation.x;
    CGFloat delta_y = location.y - previousLocation.y;

    // move button
    button.center = CGPointMake(button.center.x + delta_x,button.center.y + delta_y);
}
```

From this code i am able to move a button in the CandidateView.. Now i want to drag whole CandidateView or should I make UIView instead of UIViewcontroller.
Can anyone help me?? 
Thanks in advance..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a UIView and put everything inside of that, the UIView should fill the screen of your "UIViewController", the dragging method should work fine for that too :) Good luck! (*Another solution you might want to look into is making a UIScrollView that contains all of your objects nested in it)